# R dot product of matrix and vector using only elements from vector

Tags: r, matrix, operators, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I'm sure this is something easy to do in R.  I've attempted to search for dot products in the R documentation as well as online without success.

How can I take the dot product in R of the below matrix **y** and the named vector **x**, using only the named elements in **x**?

```
x  <- c(first=1, second=2, third=3)
x2 <- c(first=1, second=2, third=3)
y  <- as.matrix(rbind(x2,x2))
y
y %*% x
```

> y %*% x
>      [,1]
>   x2   14
>   x2   14
>
> this works

Now, I add a date field to **y**, and it fails:

```
x  <- c(first=1, second=2, third=3)
x2 <- c(first=1, second=2, third=3,anchor=as.Date('2017-04-01'))
y  <- as.matrix(rbind(x2,x2))
y
y %*% x
```

> Error in x %*% y : non-conformable arguments

This is a toy example, but I might have hundreds of unfriendly date fields in the matrix, so just removing `anchor` will not be an acceptable solution.  Automated removal of any problem fields could be considered valid.

Comment: I might be missing something but the dimensions of x and y are not compatible for matrix multiplication. You have 4 columns but there are only three elements in your vector x.

Comment: Generally it's bad news to mix data types in a matrix (here, integer and Date). Use a dataframe instead. But is there any defined meaning to multiplying a date and including it in the dot-product? You need to explain better what your computation is. You might like to store numeric fields in one dataframe/matrix, and dates in another, and join them by row-id or some key.

Comment: Note when you appended `as.Date('2017-04-01')` to your vector of numeric, it got silently coerced to the integer 17257 (days since epoch `1970-01-01`). I doubt that's what you want and your dot-product seems meaningless?

Comment: thanks for your comments- I agree that there are questions about what a dot-product even means for non-conformable arguments.  What I was wanting to do is provided by a more generalized version of the accepted solution: a dot-product between a matrix y2 and a vector x, where the matrix y2 is created by taking all intersecting column names between the matrix y and vector x.  I've added that solution to his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have only 3 columns (instead of 4) in the y matrix to do this operation with the 3 elements vector.

In your example, you can explicitly specify the columns you want to use, with their name:

```
y[,c("first","second","third")] %*% x
```

or with a range:

```
y[,1:3] %*% x
```